# UIPickerView: last value followed by first value

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uipickerview

Can anyone help me how to make the UIPickerView displays the first row's value after the last row's value, just like the UIDatePicker where after 12 the 1 will follow.

Thanks

Comment: You want to make it circular? I'm trying to find an answer, check back later maybe I'll have figured it out.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/214441/how-do-you-make-an-uipickerview-component-wrap-around

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think its possible to really make it circular, but you can fake it.

```
#define kRowsInPicker 10000

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    NSArray *localPickerData = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:
                                @"Ottawa", @"Toronto", @"Montreal", @"Winnipeg",
                                @"Saskatchewan", @"Iqaluit", @"Edomonton", nil];
    [self setPickerData:localPickerData];
    [localPickerData release];

    UIPickerView *localPicker = [[UIPickerView alloc] initWithFrame:
                                 CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 216)];
    [localPicker setDelegate:self];
    [localPicker setDataSource:self];
    localPicker.showsSelectionIndicator = YES;
    NSInteger  selectedRow = 0;
    [localPicker selectRow:(((NSInteger)((kRowsInPicker / 2) / [pickerData count])) * [pickerData count]) + (selectedRow%[pickerData count]) inComponent:0 animated:NO];
    [self setPicker:localPicker];
    [localPicker release];

    [[self view] addSubview:picker];
    [super viewDidLoad];
}
#pragma mark -
#pragma mark UIPickerViewDataSource methods

- (NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView {
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView
                                numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component {
    // usually "return [pickerData count];"
    return kRowsInPicker; // 10,000 is good, if you add a few more zeros
                          // there seems to be problems.
}

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark UIPickerViewDelegate methods

- (NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView
             titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component {
    return [pickerData objectAtIndex:row%[pickerData count]];
}
```

You can change the number of strings in pickerData and it will still work fine. The selected row selects the "first" value closest to the middle. row%[pickerData count] returns the following assuming there are 3 NSStrings in pickerData:

```
ROW             RETURNS
 0                0
 1                1
 2                2
 3                0
 4                1
 5                2
 6                0
 7                1
 8                2
 etc...
```

It will just cycle 0 through the length of the array. The confusing stuff in viewDidLoad just picks a value as close to the middle as possible using the index of the item of the array you provide in *selectedItem*. There is no performance hit or memory leak, all you have allocated is the single array. Whenever you access their selected choice, use ([localPicker selectedRowInComponent:0]%[pickerData count]). If there's something you don't understand or something I missed, please comment.
Hope this helped!

Comment: Thanks for the response. But does it will create 1000000 rows, and if I add UIImages to this row does it will create memory/performance issue.

Comment: Only the rows that are visible will be loaded, and the cells/rows/whatever they're called for UIPickerViews should be reused, I believe.

Comment: Actually, the performance will be exactly the same (unless you count the calculation of row%[pickerData count] as a performance hit).

Answer (score 0):

I have made a cyclic tableView based on `UIScrollView`. And based on this tableView, I re-implement `UIPickerView`. You might be interested in this `DLPickerView`. And this picker view has all the features that `UIPickerView` has, but also gives many new features, and custom this picker view is much easier.

https://github.com/danleechina/DLPickerView

And be aware of that this `DLPickerView` cyclically scroll is really scrolling cyclically. All the magic happened because of another class `DLTableView`.