# iphone uipickerview : image and text

Tags: objective-c, ios, uipickerview, xcode4.3

is it possible to have an image (like an icon) next to a text in `UIPickerView`
?

I saw examples of `UIPickerViews` with two Columns :one that has an image and another one with the text . this is not what I need , I need to have a single column with text and Images

Thanks.

Comment: see this question and answer, hope that is what you want

[uipickerview image with label][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4284250/uipickerview-image-with-label-in-component

Answer (score 2):

You will need to create your own view for each row of the picker. This is easy enough if it's just a UIImageView and a UILabel. You can then pass the view to your picker using this UIPickerViewDelegate method.

`- (UIView *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView viewForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component reusingView:(UIView *)view`