# Just numbers in a UIPickerView?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uipickerview

Is there a way to have a UIPickerView just have escalating numbers to infinity?
Haha.  Just kidding, but seriously, I want just a bunch of numbers going up, but I don't want to have to hard-code it all.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'm pretty sure this can be done with some cleverness (a custom integer class that supports arbitrarily large numbers, and periodically "rolling over" to a higher set of numbers once the user has scrolled through all NSIntegerMax rows (i.e. when the user scrolls to row NSIntegerMax you programmatically scroll them back to row 0 and display "row + NSIntegerMax" instead of just "row").  As they scroll through repeatedly you change it to "row + NSIntegerMax * 2", etc.

Obviously you also have to handle them changing directions are some point.

But I suspect that's what fancier than what you're looking to do.  In this case you just want to add these lines of code to your View Controller:

```
- (NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component {
    return NSIntegerMax;
}

- (NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component {
    return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", row];
}
```

Then double click on the View nib file (the *.xib file) to open it in Interface Builder, and connect the "data source" outlet to the "File Owner" (the View Controller).  That will get you as many integers as I could ever imagine someone scrolling to.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/214441/how-do-you-make-an-uipickerview-component-wrap-around). It is a variation on your problem.

Comment: Sorry, I'm quite new to Objective-C, so what is numberItems and currentValue, or how do I get them?

Comment: @Nathan, numberItems in this example is the number of items (numbers) you want to display (0-9 makes ten). Current value is the value of the current number shown.

Answer (score 0):

You could just use a UIStepper. I know you asked about UIPicker but do you really need to use that class or were you using it to explain what kind of thing you wanted