# How to make uipicker view loop?

Tags: ios, loops, uipickerview

In my app, i would like to make a uipickerview like the one in uidatepicker. 
thing is, i cant get it to repeat the values. how would i do that?
The values come from an array, that should be repeated.

Answer (score 0):

@Vladimir , it is a duplicate of [How do you make an UIPickerView component wrap around?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/214441/how-do-you-make-an-uipickerview-component-wrap-around)

There's a nice example over there... I'm sure no one will have the time to "spin" it all the way to MaxInteger :)