# IOS UIDatepicker - same style choosing a number

Tags: ios, uidatepicker

I want the same style as in UIDatePicker, but in stead of choosing a date I want to choose a number. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2):

Use for that `UIPickerview` and it's datasource and delegates methods as for `UITableView`.
[See this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/214441/how-do-you-make-an-uipickerview-component-wrap-around)