# How to implement UIPickerView for the textfield in for loop?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield, uipickerview

I am displaying text fields in a `UIView` dynamically, based on JSON response data using a `for` loop.

I need to show a `UIPickerView` for the each text field in the for loop, but it is only working for the last text field. I am unable to display a `UIPickerView` for each of the text fields. Can anyone please help me to solve this issue?

Comment: Please clarify what you are asking and provide code that you have tried.

Comment: Please mention what you have done .

Comment: You donot need to add picker view in for loop instead use one and change the array for different scenerio.

Comment: Use the tag and UITextFiled Delegates for open Picker view on startEditing textfiled. There is no need to set pickerview in ForLoop

Comment: create the pickerview in seperate at the same time assign the tag for each textfield , if you press the textfield, based on tag change the frame of pickerview and display , thats all

Comment: self.downPicker = [[DownPicker alloc] initWithTextField:self.selectField withData:listArrayValue[i]]; this code is used to setup the pickerview in textfield but it is coming only for the last textfield

Comment: Actually am displaying textfield dynamically based on the json data,in that how to set a tag for the uitextfield could please explain in detail.

Answer (score 1):

So you are inside your for loop with an i index. What we are looking here is to assign a UIPickerView as each textfield's **input view**. Try something like this...

```
//FOR LOOP BEGINS

  //Iteration - Create a textfield.
  [self.view addSubview:yourTextfield];

  //Assign a uipickerview as textfield's input view.  
  UIPickerView *pickerView = [[UIPickerView alloc] init];
  pickerView.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,300,300);
  pickerView.tag = i;
  pickerView.delegate = self;
  pickerView.showsSelectionIndicator = YES;
  textField.inputView = pickerView;
  [self.view addSubview:pickerView];

  //Iteration ends

//FOR LOOP ENDS
```

P.S. You can also add a toolbar with each pickerView to your textfield using the **inputAccessoryView**

Comment: If i add like above code am getting *** -[__NSArrayI objectAtIndex:]: index 2 beyond bounds [0 .. 1]' error .Am adding  listArray = ([listArrayValue objectAtIndex:i]; )this list array count in 
-(NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView
numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component

Answer (score 0):

You can set the number of rows to a large number, and make it start at a high value, there's little chance that the user will ever scroll the wheel for a very long time -- And even then, the worse that will happen is that they'll hit the bottom.
you can see this:
[How do you make an UIPickerView component wrap around?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/214441/how-do-you-make-an-uipickerview-component-wrap-around)